# Pole of inaccessibility returns NULLs when used in custom processing algorithm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am using Pole of inaccessibility as a part of a workflow in my custom algorithm and column, that should contain distances (dist_pole) in created layer is empty.

```py
        my_new_lyr = processing.run("native:poleofinaccessibility", {
            'INPUT': input_layer,
            'TOLERANCE': 1, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'},
                                        context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
```

When run as standalone processing algorithm from QGIS GUI, it behaves as expected - resulting field contains values. What is the cause of this?

EDIT:
The same algorithm run on the same layer in Python console (inside QGIS) also gives full proper result.

```py
in_lyr = iface.activeLayer()

my_new_lyr = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:poleofinaccessibility", {
    'INPUT': in_lyr,
    'TOLERANCE': 1, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
```

So to sum up - algorithm run from GUI, Python console and custom processing algorithm generates points correctly, however in the last case field that should contain distances (and it does in two first cases) is entirely filled with NULLs.

EDIT 2:
Apparently, empty column in custom processing algorithm appears only when the input layer is a product of another algorithm. If the input is source layer then it works fine:

```py
#...
input_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
another_input_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_2, context)

another_algo_product = processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT': another_input_layer,
                                              'FIELD': ['whatever', ],
                                              'OUTPUT': 'memory:'},
                          context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

#  produces layer with empty column
my_new_lyr = processing.run("native:poleofinaccessibility", {
    'INPUT': another_algo_product, #  <--difference
    'TOLERANCE': 1, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'},
                            context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

#  everything works as intended
my_new_lyr = processing.run("native:poleofinaccessibility", {
    'INPUT': input_layer, #  <--difference
    'TOLERANCE': 1, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'},
                            context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
```

EDIT 3:
I tried to reproduce the problem with another algorithm to see if the cause lies in `Pole of inaccessibility` or rather my algorithms structure. I chose `Convex hull`, as it similarly to `Pole of inaccessibility`, copies fields to new layer and adds new fields containing measurements (area, perimeter).
`Convex hull` works perfectly fine no matter if run from GUI or inside custom processing algorithm with derived input parameter.
I guess the problem has lie in `Pole of inaccessibility`. Minimal example:

```py
#...
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """test"""

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('input'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )


        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.OUT1,
            self.tr("out1"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry))

        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            self.OUT2,
            self.tr("out2"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry))



    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        test
        """

        input = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)


        if input is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))


        

        out1 = processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT': input,
                                           'FIELD': ['some_field',],
                                           'OUTPUT': 'memory:'},
 context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        out2 = processing.run("native:convexhull",
                       {'INPUT': out1,
                        'OUTPUT': 'memory:'},
 context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']



        (out1_sink, out1_dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUT1, context,
                                                                     out1.fields(), out1.wkbType(),
                                                                     out1.sourceCrs())

        (out2_sink, out2_dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUT2, context,
                                                                     out2.fields(), out2.wkbType(),
                                                                     out2.sourceCrs())


        for f in out1.getFeatures():
            out1_sink.addFeature(f, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

        for f in out2.getFeatures():
            out2_sink.addFeature(f, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

        return {self.OUT1: out1_dest_id,
                self.OUT2: out2_dest_id}
```

Comment: Consider adding a link to your data, or sample data, so that others can see if you have a data issue or a code issue.

Comment: I can't provide my data, but when I tried to prepare sample (exported around 5% of all features) and retested it, it works properly. Validity check comes clean for the whole layer. What are possible issues with data, that can cause error ?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing a sample of failing data. Does all of the data fail in your custom algorithm, or just some? I assume all if you are saying the column is empty?

Comment: Yes, whole column is filled with NULLs.

Comment: Try saving your "another_algo_product" result to a temporary file rather than memory. You can create a temporary file variable using something like this: `outfile = QgsProcessingUtils.generateTempFilename('output.gpkg')`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I tried also with ```QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT ``` and result is still the same.

Comment: Unfortunately it could be a bug in the code for the algorithm - if you can get a minimum reproducible case, you could raise a ticket on the QGIS bug tracker

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you for your help!